pip install PyGObject==3.50.0 complaints of stale meson even though latest meson present
Upgrading PyGobject using
pip install  PyGObject==3.50.0 --verbose

gives the error (see full error at the end)
meson-python: error: Could not find meson version 0.63.3 or newer, found 0.61.2.
            [end of output]

even though I have the latest meson
>>>pip list | grep -i -e 'meson' -e 'pygo'
meson                        1.6.1
meson-python                 0.17.1
PyGObject                    3.42.1

full error
>>>pip install  PyGObject==3.50.0 --verbose
Using pip 22.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.10)
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting PyGObject==3.50.0
  Using cached pygobject-3.50.0.tar.gz (1.1 MB)
  Running command pip subprocess to install build dependencies
  Collecting meson-python>=0.12.1
    Using cached meson_python-0.17.1-py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
  Collecting pycairo>=1.16
    Using cached pycairo-1.27.0.tar.gz (661 kB)
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Installing backend dependencies: started
    Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
    Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error

    × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
    │ exit code: 1
    ╰─> [2 lines of output]

        meson-python: error: Could not find meson version 0.63.3 or newer, found 0.61.2.
        [end of output]

    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  error: metadata-generation-failed

  × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
  ╰─> See above for output.

  note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
  hint: See above for details.
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  full command: /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/pip-standalone-pip-ldyax5i4/__env_pip__.zip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-mmevng98/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'meson-python>=0.12.
1' 'pycairo>=1.16'
  cwd: [inherit]
  Installing build dependencies ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

Environment:
>>>uname -a # Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS
Linux $HOSTNAME 6.9.3-76060903-generic #202405300957~1732141768~22.04~f2697e1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed N x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
>>>python --version
Python 3.10.12
>>>pip --version
pip 22.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.10)

